# Implementing a Matlab filter to cancel cross talk between two sensors

Tags: filter-design, matlab, cross-correlation

I have two sensors that have a cross talk between them. I would like to cancel the cross talk. For this I recorded two tracks, where sensor no.1 (called x1) has some input, and sensor no.2 (called x2) is zero.

I was told to make the following operations:

> Since your cross talk is small:
>
> 1) Simply measure the transfer function $H_{ba}(\omega)$ directly.
>
> 2) Subtract it out as follows:
>
> 2.1) Measure the transfer function from signal A to sensor B when signal B is 0.
>
> 2.2) Create a filter from this transfer function (FIR or IIR, depending on it's shape).
>
> 2.3) Now you can measure and subtract a filtered version from sensor signal A from sensor signal B:
>
> $y_b'(t) = y_b(t)-h_{ab}(t)*y_a(t)$. Where $h_{ab}(t)$ is the impulse
>   response of your cross talk filter and $*$ the convolution operator.

Here is a Matlab code that I wrote for this purpose, but its performance is really bad. If someone has a suggestion what I did wrong, or can suggest a new code I will be grateful. If I may say, a friend helped me to implement this, and I think that we did not implement the filter part, but maybe I am wrong.

```
% The files designated to measure the transfer function.
% x1 has some input. x2 is is zero, and affected by the x1.

x1 = wavread(file1); 
x2 = wavread(file2);

%The transfer function. 

Hab = fft(x2)./fft(x1);

hab=ifft(Hab);

% Some new tracks, where x3 is recorded from sensor no.1 and x4 from sensor no.2.
% All the files have the same length.

x3 = wavread(file3); 
x4 = wavread(file4);

c=conv(hab,x3);

% Subtracted signal 

x4 = x4 - c(1:length(x4));
```

The following code did not subtract the cross talk on x4.
Here are some images explaining the problem. For some frequencies the above code actually did a good job and subtracted the cross talk, and for some it did the opposite and increased the energy. `plot(abs(fft(x4)))`:

Good - Frequency energy subtracted:
[image: Good outcome, the energy of the frequency in this point was subtracted]

Bad - Frequency energy increased (!):
[image: Bad outcome, the energy increased instead of being subtracted]

Thank you!

Comment: See [this question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/953/235) to understand why $$Hab = fft(x2)./fft(x1); hab=ifft(Hab);$$ is a bad idea.

Comment: @DilipSarwate Thanks for the comment. I would like to hear your idea how to change it.

Comment: By reading the link more deeply I understand that the above solution is incorrect... If someone can help me to implement the right filter I will be so thankful.

Comment: It would be best if you could modify the sensors themselves to eliminate crosstalk.  If not, something like ICA might help?  http://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/812/29

Comment: I have already tried ICA and it doesn't work for me..

Comment: Have you thought about LMS filter? If you have a sensor that has a signal, that you know it is contaminated with a signal, that you have as reference in another sensor, then filter it out adaptively with LMS or another adaptive filter. If the levels of crosstalk between the two sensors is equal for both and of the same magnitude that the desired signal, then you have no Choice but to do Blind Source Separation (which basically is ICA as someone mentioned)

Answer (score 1):

Try using other Blind source  separation(BSS) algorithms,even Kernel BSS could be applied to remove if it is nonlinearly mixed.